# Can dm-crypt (LUKS2) be implemented on top of an UBI volume on a raw NAND flash?

Tags: filesystems, embedded, dm-crypt, flash-memory, ubifs

If I have an embedded system with a raw NAND flash, with a bad blocks table etc., as I understand it, the best way to have partitions is to have have them as [UBI volumes](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html) on top of MTD. UBI takes care of wear levelling and MTD handles erase blocks and bad blocks. Some details regarding this are explained on [this page](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/faq/general.html).

On an embedded system, typically, the bootloader stages and the Linux kernel would be verified using hardware vendor-specific Secure Boot of some kind, and then the root file system would typically be in the form of ubiblock + [dm-verity](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/verity.html) + [squashfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/qemu/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.ubi). This would be read-only and dm-verity takes care of authentication.

To implement rw partitions, typically [ubifs](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html) is used.

But for implementing secure storage aka read-writeable encrypted storage on a block device, I could use [dm-crypt (LUKS2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt). How or where the decryption key comes from is out of scope of this question.

Question 1:
Can I use dm-crypt (LUKS2) on top of an UBI volume on a raw NAND flash?

The [UBI page](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubi.html#L_ubiblock), as quoted below, implies that this is not possible, as any block device implemented on top of an UBI volume, must be read-only.

> R/O block devices on top of UBI volumes
>
> UBI allows the creation of block devices on top of UBI volumes with
> the following limitations:
>
> - **Read-only operation.**
> - Serialized I/O operation, but keep in mind the NAND driver core already serializes all I/O too.
>
> Despite these limitations, a block device is still very useful for the
> purpose of mounting **read-only**, regular file systems on top of UBI
> volumes. Take, for example, squashfs, which can be used as a
> lightweight read-only rootfs on top of a NAND device. In this case,
> the UBI layer will take care of low-level details such as bit-flip
> handling and wear-levelling.

Question 2:
If I cannot use dm-crypt (LUKS2), then what are my alternatives?

Comment: what about ubifs+fscrypt? https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fscrypt.html

Comment: @A.B Yes. That (ubifs+fscrypt) is the obvious solution. But I would like to know if dm-crypt really cannot be used on a raw NAND flash.

Comment: It was proposed r/w but not done and done only for r/o: compare http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2012-November/045012.html vs https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/mtd/ubi/Kconfig?id=9d54c8a33eec78289b1b3f6e10874719c27ce0a7 . So you should check there why it wasn't done (and maybe ask the author if needed).

Comment: Technically you can still do it on top of a filesystem: mtd - ubi - ubifs - loopback - luks (or jffs2 can be used also without ubi afaik)

Comment: @A.B Both of your comments are correct. Would you like to write an answer? For the LUKS on top of loopback on top of ubifs, you can quote [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_a_non-root_file_system#File_container).